# Importing XML into mySQL with invalid column names?

Tags: mysql, xml, database

I have this XML file that I am trying to import into mySQL. However, using the LOAD XML query does not work due to their being "-" in the variable names. How can I import this into the DB and deal with the invalid characters?:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects type="array">
  <project>
    <active type="boolean">true</active>
    <bill-by>none</bill-by>
    <billable type="boolean">true</billable>
    <budget type="decimal" nil="true"/>
    <budget-by>none</budget-by>
    <client-id type="integer">999</client-id>
    <code></code>
    <cost-budget type="decimal" nil="true"/>
    <cost-budget-include-expenses type="boolean">false</cost-budget-include-expenses>
    <created-at type="datetime">2013-06-27T18:10:26Z</created-at>
    <fees type="decimal" nil="true"/>
    <highrise-deal-id type="integer" nil="true"/>
    <hourly-rate type="decimal" nil="true"/>
    <id type="integer">38125</id>
    <name>Banking</name>
    <notify-when-over-budget type="boolean">false</notify-when-over-budget>
    <over-budget-notification-percentage type="decimal">80.0</over-budget-notification-percentage>
    <over-budget-notified-at type="date" nil="true"/>
    <show-budget-to-all type="boolean">false</show-budget-to-all>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2013-06-27T18:13:10Z</updated-at>
    <estimate nil="true"/>
    <estimate-by>none</estimate-by>
    <notes></notes>
    <hint-earliest-record-at type="NilClass">2013-06-24</hint-earliest-record-at>
    <hint-latest-record-at type="NilClass">2013-06-30</hint-latest-record-at>
    <hint-earliest-record-at>2013-06-24</hint-earliest-record-at>
    <hint-latest-record-at>2013-06-30</hint-latest-record-at>
  </project>
```

Comment: It looks like a simple textual search-and-replace could cheaply fix the file.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to fix the field names in your XML file.

Also, you have another problem with the XML file: `<hint-earliest-record-at>` and `<hint-latest-record-at>` appear twice, so you'll have to choose one either to remove or rename.

I tried an experiment:

1. Create a table with columns containing no dashes.
2. Create an updateable VIEW against that table, defining the view's column names with the dash characters
3. Load XML into the VIEW, hoping it inserts into the corresponding columns of the base table.

But this didn't work.  It inserted a row, but all the values were inserted as NULLs.

I also tested creating a VIEW with normal column names, without dashes, and then I edited the field names in the XML.  Loading this XML through the VIEW worked, and the rows were inserted into the base table.  So I know LOAD XML works with updateable VIEWs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
{'hint-earliest-record-at'}

By this way you can parse xml node with hyphen in it.